# What are best SEO practices when deleting a webpage? What return code should I use?

Tags: apache, seo

On a live site, let's say there is a page that is really outdated with old information.

Is it ok to just delete it? Or do I have to setup an Apache redirect or do a 404 or something special **for the web crawlers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your web server returns a 404 for deleted resources.

That is enough.

From the official [Google Web Master Central blog:](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/05/do-404s-hurt-my-site.html)

> **Q:** Do the 404 errors reported in Webmaster Tools affect my site’s
> ranking?
>
> **A:** 404s are a perfectly normal part of the web; the Internet
> is always changing, new content is born, old content dies, and when it
> dies it (ideally) returns a 404 HTTP response code. Search engines are
> aware of this; we have 404 errors on our own sites, as you can see
> above, and we find them all over the web. In fact, we actually prefer
> that, when you get rid of a page on your site, you make sure that it
> returns a proper 404 or 410 response code (rather than a “soft 404”).
> Keep in mind that in order for our crawler to see the HTTP response
> code of a URL, it has to be able to crawl that URL—if the URL is
> blocked by your robots.txt file we won’t be able to crawl it and see
> its response code. The fact that some URLs on your site no longer
> exist / return 404s does not affect how your site’s other URLs (the
> ones that return 200 (Successful)) perform in our search results.